# Dynamic Quartile based on Date Slicer Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a sales table where I want to initially summarize by the ship to customer name in the temp table GroupTable. From there I want to return the 1st quartile value but the issue I am having is that I would like to use PERCENTILE.INC not PERCENTILEX.INC however I was not able to find a workaround considering my table I am referencing is a temp table. My end goal is to have dynamic quartiles based on a date slicer where I do not have to create a new static table.

```
Quantile1_Sales = 
VAR GroupTable =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Sales',
        'Sales'[Customer Ship To],
        "Sales2", SUMX ( 'Sales', 'Sales'[Sales] )
    )

RETURN
   PERCENTILEX.INC ( GroupTable, [Sales2], .25 )
```

Here is an example of what the Sales table looks like below.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample dataset and and output in tabular form?

Comment: I added an example of what the sales table looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate your table inside the `PERCENTILEX` function.

See the calculation below where it takes all the selected values for `Customer Ship To` and `Date`.

### Calculation: Measure

```
Quantile1_Sales =
PERCENTILEX.INC (
    ALLSELECTED ( 'Table'[Customer Ship To], 'Table'[Date] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ) ),
    0.25
)
```

### Output

[image]

### Table Reference: `Table`

| Date | Customer | Customer Ship To | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 December 2020 | Customer A | CustA1 | 100 |
| 01 December 2020 | Customer A | CustA1 | 200 |
| 30 December 2020 | Customer B | CustB1 | 500 |
| 01 January 2021 | Customer C | CustC2 | 300 |
| 01 January 2021 | Customer D | CustD1 | 100 |
| 02 January 2021 | Customer D | CustD2 | 150 |
| 04 January 2021 | Customer A | CustA2 | 200 |
| 01 May 2021 | Customer D | CustD1 | 100 |
| 01 June 2021 | Customer F | CustF2 | 50 |